# Removing columns from data frame referenced by column index

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe called `Tweet_DataFrame`, which contains 3 columns i.e Id, name and tweet.
There are some empty rows in tweet column of `Tweet_DataFrame`. So I am using `forloop` to count number of rows in tweet column , whose length is <=5.

```
removes_index <- c()

for(i in (1:length(df$tweet.text))){
  if(nchar(df$tweet.text[i]<=5)) 
  removes_index <- c(removes_index,i)  
}
```

Now , I have index of columns whose length is less than 5 and trying remove these complete rows.

```
Tweet_DataFrame<- Tweet_DataFrame[-removes_index,]
```

But `Tweet_DataFrame` has no records , just have three columns name.
Can somebody help me to figure out that where I am getting wrong ?

DataFrame is

```
tweets.id   tweets.name tweets.text
5.51E+17    Luk     Absolutely loving these talk ads on TV. 
5.51 +17    Bree    make sure to tweet that day with the hashtag attached!
```

Comment: The parantheses is in the wrong place `if(nchar(df$tweet.text[i])<=5)`. Typographical error.

Comment: @PierreLafortune thanks , but still Tweet_DataFrame<- Tweet_DataFrame[-removes_index,] results to zero. Gives empty dataframe

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Fix the typo and the code will work. Also, there is absolutely no need for a loop here. If you add an example data frame, you can get more detailed help.

Comment: Get a few lines of your data frame and edit your question so that there is a line of code where we can copy/paste to recreate it. e.g. `DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5], c = LETTERS[1:5])`

Comment: added piece of dataframe , its a twitter data .